# Prove that $|E(G)| \geq 14$ provided $|G|=9, \delta(G)=3$ and $\Delta(G)=5$

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification

Given a simple graph $G$ with $9$ vertices, minimum vertex degree $\delta(G)=3$ and maximum vertex degree $\Delta(G)=5$. I need to prove that $|E(G)| \geq 14$ holds. We denote the degree of a vertex $v \in V(G)$ by $deg(v)$.

My solution:

$$
\sum_{v \in V(G)} deg(v) = 2|E(G)|\\
9 \cdot \delta(G) = 2|E(G)|\\
$$
Since $\delta(G)=3$, it follows that

$$
|E(G)| \geq \frac{9 \cdot 3}{2}=13.5
$$

Thus,

$$
|E(G)| \geq 14
$$

Does my solution makes sense? I keep thinking $13.5$ is  a fraction and thus its not a simple graph. Same for the maximum degree I found it to be $22.5$ rounded off to $22$.

Comment: This is correct, but written terribly badly.

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning is fine but it can be improved in order to get rid of the fraction.

**Proposition:** $|E(G)| \geq 14$.

**Proof:**
By the handshaking lemma
$$
\sum_{v \in V(G)}deg(v)=2|E(G)|
$$

Since $\delta(G)=3$, there is no vertex with degree less than $3$. Now, suppose $deg(v)=3=\delta(G)$ for all $v$ in $V(G)$. Then $G$ is $3$-regular, but due to the handshaking lemma the number of vertices with odd degree must be even. Thus, $G$ can not be $3$-regular. Hence, there is at least one vertex of degree $4$. It follows that

$$
\begin{align*}
3 \cdot (|V(G)|-1)+4 &\leq 2|E(G)|\\
\frac{3\cdot |V(G)|+1}{2} &\leq |E(G)|\\
\frac{28}{2} &\leq |E(G)|\\
14 &\leq |E(G)|
\end{align*}
$$

This completes the proof.

**Note:** The reasoning for the upper bound is similar.